# Unable to create context rendering error when run OpenGL application

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, centos, vmware-workstation, opengl

I try to run Mesa gears example and I get following error:

```
freeglut (./gears): Unable to create direct context rendering for window 'Gears'
This may hurt performance.
```

though the application runs successfully, but I guess that in future I will have much problems with productivity.

I run Linux CentOS 5 on WMvare 7. Mesa's version is 6.5
Relevant output of lspci -v gives:

```
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 9
    I/O ports at 10d0 [size=16]
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at d8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 30000000 [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information
```

Any one have idea? There is driver of vmvare for CentOS?
Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, like I understood, while I run Linux on VMware, this error isn't significant.
The solution is to install Linux on host, and then it will own direct access to graphic card.